# Rhapsody C++ code generation Turkish character problem

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, ascii, rhapsody

I have a class in Rhapsody where I do database operations (add, delete, update). I also have a class in the application interface where I show failure states. In this class, I assign the error description to the QString type member variable.

When C++ code is generated by Rhapsody;

When I assign Turkish characters to this object, when I look at the encoding of the code I generate (via notepad++), it appears as "Encode in **ANSI**".
When I don't assign Turkish characters to this object, when I look at the encoding of the code I generate (via notepad++), it appears as "Encode in **UTF-8 without BOM**".

Below is the pseudocode I wrote on the rhapsody side.

```
void save(...) {
   Journaling temp;
   temp.mComment = QString::tr("türkçe");
}
```

Below is the generated pseudocode opened with notepad++.(**Encode in ANSI**)

```
void save(...) {
   Journaling temp;
   temp.mComment = QString::tr("txFCrkxE7e");
}
```

Below is the generated pseudocode opened with Qt.(**UTF-8**)

```
void save(...) {
   Journaling temp;
   temp.mComment = QString::tr("t�rk�e");
}
```

I don't want it to behave differently in Turkish characters.

Do I have an opportunity to change the encoding of the C++ codes that will be created by Rhapsody? Or any other solution suggestions?

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `"türkçe".encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1254')` returns `tÃ¼rkÃ§e`. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].